# Role play by WhatsApp

Tags: play-by-post, play-by-chat

Although I haven't tried it myself, I've heard about people who played RPGs by email and forums. Of course, these modes involve different dynamics than tabletop games, but they seem to be plausible and quite *extended*. I was wondering whether something alike could be done by WhatsApp, taking advantage of the possibility of using speech rather than only written words.

What kind of games would be suitable?

What tools (e.g., for dice rolling) would be useful?

Any other experience-based advice?